# JRadionButton unselect automatically

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I have a jframe that ontains two JRadioButton.

```
public class jradioButtontest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public jradioButtontest() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jRadioButton1.setText("jRadioButton1");

    jRadioButton2.setText("jRadioButton2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(198, 198, 198)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton1))
            .addContainerGap(203, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(80, 80, 80)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
            .addContainerGap(225, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new jradioButtontest().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

I want when i select first JRadioButton, other JRadioButton should be unselected.
I use ready jframe, how can change netbeans generated code?
How do this?

Comment: You know that just checking the [Radiobutton tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) would have been faster the typing this question which literally mentions: "For each group of radio buttons, you need to create a ButtonGroup instance and add each radio button to it. The ButtonGroup takes care of unselecting the previously selected button when the user selects another button in the group"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, a new JRadioButton is created in its own ButtonGroup, which means they can both be selected independently.

If you want the two buttons linked so that only one can be picked at a time, you need to add:

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(jRadioButton1);
group.add(jRadioButton2);
```

After you have constructed the buttons.

Comment: As i use ready jframe, How i change netbeans generated code to add you'r code?

Answer (score 4):

Add the 2 `JRadioButtons` to a single `javax.swing.ButtonGroup` instance.

See: [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html)

Comment: As i use ready jframe, How i change netbeans generated code to add you'r code?

Comment: In `NetBeans` create a `ButtonGroup` component and set the `buttonGroup` property to that object for both `JRadioButtons` using the property editor.

Comment: I would recommend also coding Swing GUIs by hand. This will make you more familiar with the code itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ButtonGroup :

```
ButtonGroup buttongroup = new ButtonGroup();
buttongroup.add(...);
```